# Finding height of the block using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I wrote code which define height of the block with text , and give that height to block with image. But the size of image is smaller than size of the block

[image]

```
<script>
function carouselService(){
    $('.carousel-service-item').each( function(){
        var ths  = $(this),
            thsh = ths.find('.carousel-service-content').outerHeight();
        $(this).find('.carousel-service-image').css('min-height', thsh);
    });
}
carouselService();
</script>
<div class="owl-carousel carousel-service">
    <div class="carousel-service-item">
        <div class="carousel-service-content">
            <h5>Brand Developme</h5>
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo</P>
        </div>
        <!-- /carousel-service-content -->

        <div class="carousel-service-image">

        </div>
        <!-- /carousel-service-image -->
    </div>
    <!-- /carousel-service-item -->
</div>
```

Comment: please add carouselService() method to $(document).ready(function(){ carouselService();  });

Answer (score 0):

I think that **.outerHeight()** can help you.That function gets the current computed outer height (including padding, border, and optionally margin).

If you need to find just elements height without anything (padding or exc.) , you can use **.height()** function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $('element').height();

Or

offsetHeight
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

Or

Element.getBoundingClientRect()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect